# How Are the Things Magento 2 calls "mixins" Implemented?

Tags: magento2, requirejs, mixins

Magento 2's RequireJS based object systems contains a feature called "mixins".  A Magento 2 mixin isn't what a software engineer would normally think of as [a mixin/trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).  Instead, a Magento 2 mixin allows you to modify the object/value returned by a RequireJS module before that object/value is used by the main program.  You configure a Magento 2 mixin like this (via a requirejs-config.js file)

```
var config = {
    'config':{
        'mixins': {
            //the module to modify
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email': {
                //your module that will do the modification
                'Pulsestorm_RequireJsRewrite/hook':true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, you need to have `hook.js` (or whatever RequireJS module you've configured),

```
define([], function(){
    console.log("Hello");
    return function(theObjectReturnedByTheModuleWeAreHookingInto){
        console.log(theObjectReturnedByTheModuleWeAreHookingInto);
        console.log("Called");
        return theObjectReturnedByTheModuleWeAreHookingInto;
    };
});
```

return a function.  Magento will call this function, passing in a reference to the "module" you want to modify.  In our example this will be the object returned by the RequireJS module `Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email`.  This may also be a function, or even a scaler value (depending on what the RequireJS module returns).

This system appears to be called `mixins` because it allows you to create mixin like behavior if the object returned by the original RequireJS module supports the `extend` method.

```
define([], function(){
    'use strict';
    console.log("Hello");

    var mixin = {
        ourExtraMethod = function(){
            //...
        }
    };

    return function(theObjectReturnedByTheModuleWeAreHookingInto){
        console.log(theObjectReturnedByTheModuleWeAreHookingInto);
        console.log("Called");


        return theObjectReturnedByTheModuleWeAreHookingInto.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

However, the system itself is just a way to hook into module object creation.

Preamble finished -- does anyone know **how** Magento has implemented this functionality?  The RequireJS website [doesn't seem to mention mixins](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Arequirejs.org%20mixins) (although Google thinks you [might want RequireJS's plugin page](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html)).

Outside of `requirejs-config.js` files, Magento 2's core javascript only mentions `mixins` in three files

```
$ find vendor/magento/ -name '*.js' | xargs ack mixins
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/apply/main.js
73:                            if (obj.mixins) {
74:                                require(obj.mixins, function () {
79:                                    delete obj.mixins;

vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/apply/scripts.js
39:            if (_.has(obj, 'mixins')) {
41:                data[key].mixins = data[key].mixins || [];
42:                data[key].mixins = data[key].mixins.concat(obj.mixins);
43:                delete obj.mixins;

vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/requirejs/mixins.js
5:define('mixins', [
24:     * Adds 'mixins!' prefix to the specified string.
30:        return 'mixins!' + name;
76:     * Iterativly calls mixins passing to them
80:     * @param {...Function} mixins
84:        var mixins = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
86:        mixins.forEach(function (mixin) {
96:         * Loads specified module along with its' mixins.
102:                mixins   = this.getMixins(path),
103:                deps     = [name].concat(mixins);
111:         * Retrieves list of mixins associated with a specified module.
114:         * @returns {Array} An array of paths to mixins.
118:                mixins = config[path] || {};
120:            return Object.keys(mixins).filter(function (mixin) {
121:                return mixins[mixin] !== false;
126:         * Checks if specified module has associated with it mixins.
137:         * the 'mixins!' plugin prefix if it's necessary.
172:    'mixins'
173:], function (mixins) {
237:        deps = mixins.processNames(deps, context);
252:            queueItem[1] = mixins.processNames(lastDeps, context);
```

The `mixins.js` file appears to be a RequireJS plugin (based on the `!...` mentions in the comments -- is this right?) but it's not 100% clear when `main.js` or `scripts.js` are invoked by Magento, or how the custom `mixins` configuration makes it from `requirejs-config.js` into the listener/hook system described above.

Does anyone have an explanation for how this system was/is implemented/architected, with an eye towards being able to debug why a "mixin" may or may not be applied?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd like to go straight to your questions and then I'll try to make it clear on what you can actually do with the *mixins* plugin. So, first things first.

#### Implementation

The main thing here is the ability of any RequireJS plugin to completely take over the loading process of certain files.
This allows to modify the export value of a module before it will be passed as a resolved dependency.

Take a look at this sketchy implementation of what Magento custom *mixins* plugin is actually is:

```
// RequireJS config object.
// Like this one: app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/requirejs-config.js
{
    //...

    // Every RequireJS plugin is a module and every module can
    // have it's configuration.
    config: {
        sampleMixinPlugin: {
            'path/to/the/sampleModule': ['path/to/extension']
        }
    }
}

define('sampleMixinPlugin', [
    'module'
] function (module) {
    'use strict';

    // Data that was defined in the previous step.
    var mixinsMap = module.config();

    return {
        /**
         * This method will be invoked to load a module in case it was requested
         * with a 'sampleMixinPlugin!' substring in it's path,
         * e.g 'sampleMixinPlugin!path/to/the/module'.
         */
        load: function (name, req, onLoad) {
            var mixinsForModule = [],
                moduleUrl = req.toUrl(name),
                toLoad;

            // Get a list of mixins that need to be applied to the module.
            if (name in mixinsMap) {
                mixinsForModule = mixinsMap[name];
            }

            toLoad = [moduleUrl].concat(mixinsForModule);

            // Load the original module along with mixins for it.
            req(toLoad, function (moduleExport, ...mixinFunctions) {
                // Apply mixins to the original value exported by the sampleModule.
                var modifiedExport = mixinFunctions.reduce(function (result, mixinFn) {
                        return mixinFn(result);
                }, moduleExport);

                // Tell RequireJS that this is what was actually loaded.
                onLoad(modifiedExport);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The last and the most challenging part is to dynamically prepend the 'sampleMixinPlugin!' substring to the requested modules. To do this we
intercept `define` and `require` invocations and modify the list of dependencies before they will be processed by the original RequireJS load method.
It's a little bit tricky and I'd recommend to look at the implementation `lib/web/mage/requirejs/mixins.js` if you wanna how it works.

#### Debugging

I'd recommend this steps:

- Make sure that the configuration for 'mixins!' plugin is actually [there](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/web/mage/requirejs/mixins.js#L117).
- Check that the path to a module is [being modified](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/web/mage/requirejs/mixins.js#L152). I.e. it turns from `path/to/module` to `mixins!path/to/module`.

And the last but not least, `requiresjs/mixins.js` has nothing to do with the `main.js` or `script.js` modules as they can only extend the configuration being passed from the `data-mage-init` attribute:

```
<div data-mage-init='{
    "path/to/module": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "mixins": ["path/to/configuration-modifier"]
    }
}'></div>
```

I mean that the former two files don't mess with the value returned by a module, instead they pre-process configuration of an instance.

#### Usage Examples

To begin with I'd like to set the record straight that so called "mixins" (you're right about the misnaming) actually allow to modify the exported value of a module in any way you want. I'd say that this is a way more generic mechanism.

Here is a quick sample of adding extra functionality to the function being exported by a module:

```
// multiply.js
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Multiplies two numeric values.
     */
    function multiply(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    return multiply;
});

// extension.js
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (multiply) {
        // Function that allows to multiply an arbitrary number of values.
        return function () {
            var args = Array.from(arguments);

            return args.reduce(function (result, value) {
                return multiply(result, value);
            }, 1);
        };
    };
});

// dependant.js
define(['multiply'], function (multiply) {
    'use strict';

    console.log(multiply(2, 3, 4)); // 24
});
```

You can implement an actual mixin for any object/function returned by a module and you don't need to depend on the `extend` method at all.

Extending a constructor function:

```
// construnctor.js
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    function ClassA() {
        this.property = 'foo';
    }

    ClassA.prototype.method = function () {
        return this.property + 'bar';
    }

    return ClassA;
});

// mixin.js
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (ClassA) {
        var originalMethod = ClassA.prototype.method;

        ClassA.prototype.method = function () {
            return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments) + 'baz';
        };

        return ClassA;
    }
});
```

I hope that this answers your questions.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you!  Just what I was looking for -- the only other question I'd have is -- what does the `mixins` configuration do in `x-magento-init` and `data-mage-init` configurations?  i.e. -- in you above example, would `path/to/configuration-modifier` also return a callback that could modify the configuration data?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, precisely! It's supposed to return a callback from which you could modify the configuration data.

Comment: you seem to know your way around the front end stuff pretty well -- any insight on these two questions? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147899/what-does-the-magento-ui-js-lib-knockout-extender-bound-nodes-requirejs-module-d  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147880/what-does-the-initunique-method-setup-in-uielement-objects

Answer (score 4):

To round out [Denis Rul's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/46470/denis-rul) [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/143006/4).

So, if you look at a Magento page, here are the three `<script/>` tags that load Magento.

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://magento.example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://magento.example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://magento.example.com/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js"></script>
```

This is RequireJS itself (`require.js`), the `mixins.js` plugin, and the [merged RequireJS configuration](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs/) (`requirejs-config.js`).

The `mixins.js` file defines a RequireJS plugin.  This plugin is responsible for loading and calling the RequireJS modules that listen for other RequireJS module's instantiation.

This plugin **also** contains a requirejs program after it defines the mixin plugin.

```
require([
    'mixins'
], function (mixins) {
    'use strict';
    //...

    /**
     * Overrides global 'require' method adding to it dependencies modfication.
     */
    window.require = function (deps, callback, errback, optional) {
        //...
    };

    //...

    window.define = function (name, deps, callback) {
        //...
    };

    window.requirejs = window.require;
});
```

This second program loads the just defined `mixins` plugin as a dependency, and then **redefines** the global `require`, `define` and `requirejs` functions.  This redefinition is what allows the "not really a mixin" system to hook into RequireJS module's initial instantiation before passing things back to the regular functions.