# What does the "initUnique" Method setup in uiElement Objects?

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, requirejs, uielement

In Magento 2's `uiElement` objects, one of the initialization methods is named `initUnique`

```
initialize: function () {
    this._super()
        .initObservable()
        .initModules()
        .initStatefull()
        .initLinks()
        .initUnique();

    return this;
},
```

The `init` functions usually setup some feature or magic in the `uiElement` objects.  For example, the `initLinks` method sets up [the imports/exports default](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_uiclass_data_features/).

However, after examining the source of `initUnique`

```
initUnique: function () {
    var update = this.onUniqueUpdate.bind(this),
        uniqueNs = this.uniqueNs;

    this.hasUnique = this.uniqueProp && uniqueNs;

    if (this.hasUnique) {
        this.source.on(uniqueNs, update, this.name);
    }

    return this;
},
```

The `onUniqueUpdate` callback it sets up in the `source` property it binds and sets up if certain object properties are populated.

```
onUniqueUpdate: function (name) {
    var active = name === this.name,
        property = this.uniqueProp;

    this[property](active);
}
```

and the related `setUnique` method

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/element/element.js
setUnique: function () {
    var property = this.uniqueProp;

    if (this[property]()) {
        this.source.set(this.uniqueNs, this.name);
    }

    return this;
},
```

It's still not clear what this "unique" object feature does, or how a `uiElement` object needs to be configured for the "unique" feature to take effect.

It seems related to the `source` property, which is populated during the call to initModules

```
initModules: function () {
    var modules = this.modules || {};

    _.each(modules, function (name, property) {
        this[property] = this.requestModule(name);
    }, this);

    if (!_.isFunction(this.source)) {
        this.source = registry.get(this.provider);
    }

    return this;
},
```

but there's too many loose threads to know what, if anything, is being kept or made unique, or if "unique" is a red herring and this feature actually does something else.

I'm hoping someone else here knows and can shed some light on the matter with a **plain english** explanation of what this feature does in the UI Component system.