# What does the Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes RequireJS Module Do?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs

The Knockout.js bootstrap module in Magento 2 includes the following module via a `define` dependency.

```
 Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes
```

Technically speaking, this module creates wrappers for the `ko.applyBindings` and `ko.cleanNode` methods. These wrappers will stash certain view models and nodes in a private javascript `WeakMap`, and then return a single registry object that will let you access items in the `WeakMap`.

However, it's not clear what end-user-programmer facing features this enables.  Does anyone here know what the `Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes` module is actually for?  Or is familiar enough with Knockout.js internals to figure things out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes` registry will, theoretically, let you fetch a list of HTML-DOM nodes that are `scoped`ed to a particular view model.  i.e. you should be able to say something like this

```
boundNodes = requirejs('Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes');
reg = requirejs('uiRegistry');    
viewModel = reg.get('customer');
console.log( boundNodes.get(viewModel) );
```

and get back a reference to the `li` node that's scoped with `customer`

```
<li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
    <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
    <span data-bind="text: new String('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
    <span data-bind="html:'Default welcome msg!'"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

You'll notice the use of *theoretically* and *should*.  The problem, per this community forum thread, is there's been an undiscovered bug in the `Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes` module [lurking for a while now](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/What-does-the-Magento-Ui-js-lib-knockout-extender-bound-nodes/m-p/55791#U55791).  It is not, as of the 2.1.x branch, code you can rely on.